# How to share image in instagram?Swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

Sorry for the question without a code.But i didn't find anywhere to look for.
I want to share image with title in instagram? How can i do that?

**Any help would be great**

Comment: Unless something's changed that I don't know about, you can't post images to the instgram api.  You might want to try a more generic sharing option: http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

Comment: You want to open the Instagram application with an image provided by your application? Or do you want to upload an image to a users Instagram on your applications behalf?

Comment: @Logan thanks..i will be looking into that ....

Comment: @DanielStorm i want to do the second one you mentioned..how am i gonna do that?

Comment: @copeME you can do what DanielStorm mentioned with OAuth Swift. OAuth is the only way you can do anything with a person's account (uploading, following, etc.) and the third party library mentioned below takes care of it all for you. I would highly recommend using it.

Answer (score 27):

if you don't want to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`

**SWIFT 5 update**

```
import Photos
...

func postImageToInstagram(image: UIImage) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

        if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {

            let url = URL(string: "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=\(lastAsset.localIdentifier)")!

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            } else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Instagram is not installed", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Bro.. That i was looking for. Is it possible to do the same without saving the picture to photo gallery?

Comment: I'm just wondering why instagram://library is not in the Instagram documentation. Anyway, it works for me. Thx!

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i was looking for.
Although one has to be aware, that his requires your app to have write access to the photo library. Maybe a blocker for some.

Comment: How I can share also video?

Answer (score 11):

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    
    var yourImage: UIImage?
    var documentController: UIDocumentInteractionController!
    
    func shareToInstagram() {
        
        let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")
        
        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {
            
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage!, 100)
            
            let captionString = "caption"
            
            let writePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")
            if imageData?.writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true) == false {
                
                return
                
            } else {
                let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)
                
                self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileURL)
                
                self.documentController.delegate = self
                
                self.documentController.UTI = "com.instagram.exlusivegram"
                
                self.documentController.annotation = NSDictionary(object: captionString, forKey: "InstagramCaption")
                self.documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)
                
            }
            
        } else {
            print(" Instagram isn't installed ")
        }
    }
}
```

Now this still wont work with iOS 9, so you will have to go to your apps info.plist, add "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" type: Array, and add the URL Scheme in this case "instagram".

Comment: To make this work, need to add the following in plist : <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>

Comment: http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

Comment: i am getting `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The file couldn’t be saved because the specified URL type isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5B80A983-5571-44A5-80D7-6A7B065800B5/tmp/instagram.igo}` at `try imageData.write(to: writePath)` in iOS 10.1 swift 3

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3.0**  Version :

```
 @IBAction func shareInstagram(_ sender: Any) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            //Share To Instagram:
            let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://app")
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL!) {

                let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100)
                let writePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")

                do {
                    try imageData?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath), options: .atomic)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)
                self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: fileURL)
                self.documentController.delegate = self
                self.documentController.uti = "com.instagram.exlusivegram"

                if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                    self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.bounds, in: self.view, animated: true)
                } else {
                    self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.IGBarButton, animated: true)
                }
            } else {
                print(" Instagram is not installed ")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method does not seem to work anymore, see example [repo](https://github.com/attilaroy/share-instagram-swift/issues/1)

Answer (score 4):

Here try this code

```
@IBAction func shareContent(sender: UIButton) {
    
    let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
    let objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [image!]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: objectsToShare,
        applicationActivities: nil
    )
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
        UIActivityTypePostToFacebook
    ]
    self.presentViewController(
        activityViewController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how you share to Instagram (or anywhere else) in modern iOS.  You never try to "share from inside the app".

Comment: Just a heads up this is broken in iOS 13.1, I don't think it is your code, I think Apple has broken some or all share extensions