# Filter the apps suggested by UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: swift, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

I want to share images to Instagram from my iOS application using `UIDocumentInteractionController` but the controller should display only Instagram icon while sharing.

Is it possible to filter the apps suggested by the `UIDocumentInteractionController`?

Comment: Update question with your code. What you have done so far?

Comment: I've no idea how to implement this, I've just used an inbuilt method of UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate.

Comment: I don't think you can filter the apps that are shown because they all can handle that particular document

Comment: Use UIActivityViewController if you want to filter.

Comment: Can you check this answer out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38550562/3359906